# Rspec test 'cancan'. Uninitialized constant Ability (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to testing 'cancan' gem.But when I running rspec, shell show me an error

```
uninitialized constant Ability (NameError)
```

this is my spec_ability.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require "cancan/matchers"

describe Ability do
  it "user has ability" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    ability = Ability.new(user)
    expect(ability).to be_able_to(:destroy, Project.new(:user => user))
  end
end
```

and this is model ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

full trace

```
/home/weare138/timonin/spec/models/ability_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Ability (NameError)
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

users was generated factory 'users.rb'

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: In which folder did you place the `ability.rb`?

Comment: what RSpec version do you use? if '3.x' then try to change `require 'spec_helper'` to `require 'rails_helper'`

Comment: 2fiveigit in models folder, 2gotva 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix for this would indeed be to `require 'rails_helper'` instead of `require 'spec_helper'`.

This will load the Rails stuff, and will add the `Ability` class to the load path. Then it can be auto loaded when used in the spec.

Alternatively, you could load the ability class manually in your spec:

```
require_relative '../../app/models/ability'
```